# Checkout multiple folders from Starteam using stcmd command

Tags: starteam

How can I checkout multiple folders from Starteam using stcmd command. I couldn't find the syntax in Starteam's user manual.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of StarTeam.

If you are checking out a single folder recursively then just include the -is flag to recurse the operation.

If you are looking to check out multiple folders not under the same parent, then you will probably need to do this with multiple calls to stcmd.exe, as paths cannot be included in the file list (i.e. you cannot check out folder1/*.*, folder2/*.* in a single call to stcmd.)

If you are using StarTeam 12.0 or later there is a new stateful client that may make the process a little bit nicer for you, as you can basically script multiple checkout commands into a single session.